# Have the Douwd made any other appearances in Star Trek canon other than "The Survivors"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, aliens, star-trek-eu

The Douwd made their one and only Star Trek TNG appearance in episode 3x03: "[The Survivors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Survivors_(episode))". They were a species of extraordinary powers, but with a pacifistic nature. As Captain Picard once said about one of them:

> We leave behind a being of extraordinary power... and conscience.

I'm curious if there is ever another mention of the species in any of the other Star Trek series or books.

Comment: I'm not sure we should extrapolate from Kevin Uxbridge's personality to *all* Douwd. Humans are all different; There are pacifist humans, there are aggressive humans, and so forth. That probably also applies to other species.

Comment: Follow the links from the episode page: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Douwd https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Douwd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Douwd have been mentioned (in passing) in four officially licensed Star Trek books but have never appeared as a character, other than in the original TNG episode, Survivors.

**[Q-Strike](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Q_Continuum)**

> Even the Q recognize a common consensual reality, a certain
>   metaphysical bedrock or foundation that transcends even our own
>   infinite command over time and space, energy and matter. The
>   alternative is utter chaos, and we all understand chat. So do the
>   Organians and the Metrons **and the Douwd and all of the other truly
>   advanced intelligences**.    But not 0, not anymore. He's different
>   now.

**[Q Space](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Q_Continuum)**

> Machines were born, sometimes surpassing their makers, and fragile
>   life-forms dared the void between worlds in vessels of every
>   description, leaving their tracks on a thousand systems before
>   shedding their physical forms entirely to become numinous beings of
>   pure thought. There were the Organians, Picard realized, and the
>   Metrons and the Thasians and the Zalkonians **and the Douwd.**

**[Buried Age :](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Buried_Age)**

> **She had heard tales of a secretive people called the Douwd, beings to
>   whom imaginative thought defined reality**, so that they lived lives of
>   illusion and pretense, rarely revealing themselves for what they
>   were-although the one thing they would never do was use their
>   deceptions to harm others.

**[X-Men (Planet-X)](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_X)**

> Their frequent visitor from the Q Continuum had demonstrated his
>   amazing powers for them time and again. Once, he had even granted the
>   first officer a taste of them. “Or the Traveler,” he continued, “who
>   can manipulate the very fabric of space and time. **And don’t forget the
>   Douwd, who was able to wipe out an entire race with a single thought.”**

Comment: Star Trek X-Men? 

Comment: @armadillo - There is no crossover so stupid that it hasn't happened in a comic. The [Infestation](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Infestation,_Issue_1) comics (Star Trek/Transformers/Ghostbusters/Ninja Turtles/Dungeons and Dragons) are a personal favourite,

Comment: @Valorum Funnily enough, the book had Picard and Xavier be lookalikes even before Stewart played Xavier.

Comment: While the Douwd are referenced, the Husnock (and the aftermath of Kevin Uxbridge's actions) are the main MacGuffin in the book https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Fortune_of_War

Answer (score 5):

Memory Alpha's [entry on the Douwd](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Douwd) indicates that the episode you reference '[The Survivors](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Survivors_%28episode%29)' is their only appearance so far.  I've seen them pop up once or twice in Fanfic, but never in any of the official books.

Comment: While the Douwd are referenced, the Husnock (and the aftermath of Kevin Uxbridge's actions) are the main MacGuffin in the book https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Fortune_of_War